# Вывод времени в javascript

Tags: jquery, дата, javascript, время

Вопрос, наверное, глупый, но. Задаю дату таким образом:

```
 f_time = new Date();
 f_hour = f_time.getHours();
 f_minute = f_time.getMinutes();
```

Вывожу на страницу через jquery:

```
$(".time").text(f_hour + ":" + f_minute);
```

Время представляется в виде 5:8 вместо кошерного 5:08.
Вопрос: что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените строку

```
f_minute = f_time.getMinutes();
```

на

```
f_minute = (f_time.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '' ) + f_time.getMinutes() ;
```

Comment: Красивое решение, спасибо.

Comment: @Kirp т.е. вызвать два раза функцию для вас красивее чем один ? :)

Answer (score 2):

Наверное как-то так.

```
var f_minute = ('0'+f_time.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
```

(превратить в строку '0'+minutes и взять последние два символа)