# Часы с временем Голландии

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, canvas

Как сделать такие часы с временем Голландии?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Берете, например, https://codepen.io/yumeeeei/pen/qRwOOb + moment.js

Comment: а как поставить время страны определенной?

Comment: @Aslero Просто, по часовому поясу.

Comment: @Aslero, `moment().tz("Europe/Amsterdam")`

Comment: а как в этом примере установить moment().tz("Europe/Amsterdam")

Answer (score 4):

Пожалуйста:

```js
// Define the canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("clock");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Define some size
var radius = canvas.height / 2;

// Center the ctx
ctx.translate(radius,radius);

// Draw the Clock every second
setInterval(drawClock, 1000);

// Draw the Clock 
function drawClock() {
 drawFace(ctx, radius);
 drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
 drawTime(ctx,radius);
 drawNose(ctx,radius);
}

// Define how to draw the Face
function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
 ctx.fillStyle = "#F8F8FF";
 ctx.fill();
}

// Define how to draw the Numbers
function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
 var ang;
 var num;
 
 // Define the text styles
 ctx.font = "14px 'Lato'";
 ctx.fillStyle = "black";
 ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
 ctx.textAlign = "center";
 
 // Rotate and put number and rotate back
 for(num=1; num<=12; num++) {
  ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
  ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
 }
}

// Draw the Hands depends on current time
function drawTime(ctx,radius) {
 // Get the current time
 var now = moment().tz("Europe/Amsterdam");
 var hour = now.hour();
 var minute = now.minutes();
 var second = now.seconds();
 
 // Draw the Hour Hand
 hour=hour%12;
 hour=(hour*Math.PI/6)+(minute*Math.PI/(6*60))+(second*Math.PI/(360*60));
 drawHand(ctx, hour, radius*0.4, 4, "black");
 // Draw the Minute Hand
 minute=(minute*Math.PI/(30))+(second*Math.PI/(30*60));
 drawHand(ctx, minute, radius*0.6, 2, "black");
 // Draw the Second Hand
 second=(second*Math.PI/30);
 drawHand(ctx, second, radius*0.75, 1, "#DC143C");
}

// Define how to draw the Hands
function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width, color){
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.lineWidth = width;
 ctx.lineCap = "round";
 ctx.moveTo(0,0);
 ctx.rotate(pos);
 ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
 ctx.strokeStyle = color;
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.rotate(-pos);
}

function drawNose(ctx, radius) {
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(0, 0, radius*.08, 0, 2*Math.PI);
 ctx.fillStyle = "#DC143C";
 ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100");
html,
body,
.flex-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.caption {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.14/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>

<div class="flex-container">
  <canvas id="clock" width="240" height="240"></canvas>
  <div class="caption">Время в Амстердаме</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понял, вы не разбираетесь как это самостоятельно реализовать на JavaScript?
Впринципе, это не является проблемой используйте в таком случае библиотеку [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

#### Также пересмотрите некоторые готовые решения на SO:

[Вывод времени в javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/245460/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javascript?rq=1)
[Javascript. Формат времени](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768847/javascript-%d0%a4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8/768866#768866)
[Как выбрать зону времени?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/248660/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8?rq=1)

Что касается самостоятельной реализации таких же часов как в вашей ссылке, необходимы будут познания в [`canvas`](https://webref.ru/html/canvas).

Изучите библиотеку [LibCanvas](https://libcanvas.github.io/) . Возможно с ней вас будет намного проще реализовать, то что вы задумали.
Перечитайте статьи на [habrahabr.ru](https://habrahabr.ru/search/?q=%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B+canvas#h) , связанные с вашим вопросом.

Comment: @Aslero Если вы получили ответ который искали, в сообществе принято его принимать. Выберите тот, что вам подошел или отпишитесь, что не получается. Ваша реакция на ответы и обсуждения важна для всего сообщества. Кто-либо позже будет искать такую информацию и хорошо, если она уже есть, и оформлена достойно.