# стрелочки часов canvas js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Как нарисовать линии, как на картинке, только на картинке кружочки, а мне нужно линии[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
// Defint the canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("clock");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Define some size
var radius = canvas.height / 2;

// Center the ctx
ctx.translate(radius,radius);

// Draw the Clock every second
setInterval(drawClock, 1000);

// Draw the Clock 
function drawClock() {
 drawFace(ctx, radius);
 drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
 drawTime(ctx,radius);
 drawNose(ctx,radius);
}

// Define how to draw the Face
function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
 ctx.fillStyle = "#F8F8FF";
 ctx.fill();
}

// Define how to draw the Numbers
function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
 var ang;
 var num;
 
 // Define the text styles
 ctx.font = "14px 'Lato'";
 ctx.fillStyle = "black";
 ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
 ctx.textAlign = "center";
 
 // Rotate and put number and rotate back
 for(num=1; num<=12; num++) {
  ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
  ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
 }
}

// Draw the Hands depends on current time
function drawTime(ctx,radius) {
 // Get the current time
 var now = new Date();
 var hour = now.getHours();
 var minute = now.getMinutes();
 var second = now.getSeconds();
 
 // Draw the Hour Hand
 hour=hour%12;
 hour=(hour*Math.PI/6)+(minute*Math.PI/(6*60))+(second*Math.PI/(360*60));
 drawHand(ctx, hour, radius*0.4, 4, "black");
 // Draw the Minute Hand
 minute=(minute*Math.PI/(30))+(second*Math.PI/(30*60));
 drawHand(ctx, minute, radius*0.6, 2, "black");
 // Draw the Second Hand
 second=(second*Math.PI/30);
 drawHand(ctx, second, radius*0.75, 1, "#DC143C");
}

// Define how to draw the Hands
function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width, color){
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.lineWidth = width;
 ctx.lineCap = "round";
 ctx.moveTo(0,0);
 ctx.rotate(pos);
 ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
 ctx.strokeStyle = color;
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.rotate(-pos);
}

function drawNose(ctx, radius) {
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(0, 0, radius*.08, 0, 2*Math.PI);
 ctx.fillStyle = "#DC143C";
 ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
 
html
body
.flex-container
 width 100%
 height 100%

.flex-container
 display flex
 justify-content center
 align-items center
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
 <canvas id="clock" width="240" height="240"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: семь красных линий, из них три - прозрачным цветом, все перпендикулярны

Comment: это понятно, я чол-то не допру как их в этом цикле рисовать
for(num=1; num<=12; num++) {

Comment: Один час - 30 градусов, одна минута - 6.

Comment: Продолжение движения: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769130/%d0%a7%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%93%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b8/769478#769478 :) Так и допишем до самого конца :)

Answer (score 4):

Первый раз писал JS код, но я думаю это то что вы хотели.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
// Defint the canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("clock");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Define some size
var radius = canvas.height / 2;

// Center the ctx
ctx.translate(radius,radius);

// Draw the Clock every second
setInterval(drawClock, 1000);

// Draw the Clock
function drawClock() {
    drawFace(ctx, radius);
    drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
    drawTime(ctx,radius);
    drawSteps(ctx, radius)
    drawNose(ctx, radius)
}

// Define how to draw the Face
function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#F8F8FF";
    ctx.fill();
}

// Define how to draw the Numbers
function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
    var ang;
    var num;

    // Define the text styles
    ctx.font = "14px 'Lato'";
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";

    // Rotate and put number and rotate back
    for(num=1; num<=12; num++) {
        ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
        ctx.rotate(ang);
        ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.85);
        ctx.rotate(-ang);
        ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
        ctx.rotate(ang);
        ctx.translate(0, radius*0.85);
        ctx.rotate(-ang);
    }
}

// Draw the Hands depends on current time
function drawTime(ctx,radius) {
    // Get the current time
    var now = new Date();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var minute = now.getMinutes();
    var second = now.getSeconds();

    // Draw the Hour Hand
    hour=hour%12;
    hour=(hour*Math.PI/6)+(minute*Math.PI/(6*60))+(second*Math.PI/(360*60));
    drawHand(ctx, hour, radius*0.4, 4, "black");
    // Draw the Minute Hand
    minute=(minute*Math.PI/(30))+(second*Math.PI/(30*60));
    drawHand(ctx, minute, radius*0.6, 2, "black");
    // Draw the Second Hand
    second=(second*Math.PI/30);
    drawHand(ctx, second, radius*0.75, 1, "#DC143C");
}

// Define how to draw the Hands
function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width, color){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.rotate(pos);
    ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.rotate(-pos);
}

function drawSteps(ctx, radius){
    for(num=1; num<=12; num++) {
        ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
        ctx.rotate(ang);
        ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.85);
        ctx.rotate(-ang);
        drawStep(ctx, ang, 0, 4, "black");
        ctx.rotate(ang);
        ctx.translate(0, radius*0.85);
        ctx.rotate(-ang);
    }

    for(num=1; num<=60; num++) {
        ang = num * Math.PI / 30;
        ctx.rotate(ang);
        ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.85);
        ctx.rotate(-ang);
        drawStep(ctx, ang, 0, 1, "black");
        ctx.rotate(ang);
        ctx.translate(0, radius*0.85);
        ctx.rotate(-ang);
    }
}

function drawStep(ctx, pos, length, width, color){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.rotate(pos);
    ctx.moveTo(0,-10);
    ctx.lineTo(0,-17);
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.rotate(-pos);
}

function drawNose(ctx, radius) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, radius*.08, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#DC143C";
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Comment: спасибо, немного подкорректировал и супер

Comment: Пожалуйста. Рад был помочь.

Comment: @Aslero Галочка слева - щелк. На этом ресурсе считается хорошим тоном отмечать ответы, которые решили Вашу проблему, как принятые.

Answer (score 0):

пробовал так но не выводит

```
 var radiusClock = ctx.width/2 - 10;
        var xCenterClock = ctx.width/2;
        var yCenterClock = ctx.height/2;
         var radiusNum = radiusClock - 10; //Радиус расположения рисочек    


    var radiusNum = radiusClock - 10; //Радиус расположения рисочек 
        var radiusPoint;
        for(var tm = 0; tm < 60; tm++){
          ctx.beginPath();
          if(tm % 5 == 0){radiusPoint = 5;}else{radiusPoint = 2;} //для выделения часовых рисочек
          var xPointM = xCenterClock + radiusNum * Math.cos(-6*tm*(Math.PI/180) + Math.PI/2);
          var yPointM = yCenterClock - radiusNum * Math.sin(-6*tm*(Math.PI/180) + Math.PI/2);
          ctx.arc(xPointM, yPointM, radiusPoint, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
          ctx.stroke();
          ctx.closePath();
        }
```